# Left Join in hive not passing filters before doing a scan

Tags: sql, apache-spark, hive, left-join, hiveql

I am using Hive 2.3.5
Spark version 2.3.3

When I run the following query on hive it fails ..saying trying to scan too many partitions.

```
select t1.A, t2.B 
   from t1 left join t2 on t1.x = t2.x
    where t1.x = 'abc'
```

vs when I run this, it works fine:

```
 select t1.A, t2.B 
 from t1 left join t2 on t1.x = t2.x
    where t1.x = 'abc'
    and t2.x = 'abc'
```

Why do I need to pass the explicit filter (t2.x='abc') again on the table t2 when I am already doing join on t1.x = t2.x
where t1.x = 'abc'?

Normal join works fine without the additional filter needed, but not let join

Answer (score 0):

Optiimizer not always can push down predicates because it is not intelligent enough. And WHERE is being applied after join most probably, causing scanning too many rows.
Probably PPD works fine with INNER JOIN. EXPLAIN plan may give more information about plan.

But apart from this, there is one more issue.

You are saying that INNER join works ok... Look:

Your two queries are completely different. First one is a LEFT JOIN. If t2 does not contain rows where t2.x = 'abc', it will return rows from t1.

Second one has different behavior, it is an INNER JOIN really because this predicate in the where `t2.x = 'abc'` does not allow NULLs, filtering out records which are not joined with t2. Check it, you are selecting only joined records = INNER JOIN. If table does not contain rows where t2.x = 'abc', second query will not return any rows.

Try adding one more join condition to the ON instead of WHERE, **this will look more like LEFT JOIN**:

```
select t1.A, t2.B 
 from t1 left join t2 on t1.x = t2.x and t2.x='abc' 
    where t1.x = 'abc'
```

I am not saying that this will resolve the issue with too many partitions scanned, I'm just saying that this will be real left join, not inner, and predicate will be applied to t2 before join.

Another way is using filtering in the subquery before join.

```
   select t1.A, t2.B 
     from (select * from t1 where t1.x = 'abc') t1 
         left join (select * from t2 where t2.x = 'abc') t2 
                  on t1.x = t2.x
```

Comment: My both queries (with and without t2.x = 'abc') work fine gives exactly same result when I run on a smaller DB/dataset. But without the Predicate, the query fails on a full size dataset. Your suggestion would work but we don't want to add this predicate twice..as this query is auto-generated and can break on other columns in future,

Comment: @PuneetGarg You may be happy with the result. But it works not like left join. If you carefully check, you will see that presence of this predicate in the WHERE and t2.x = 'abc' converts it into INNER JOIN. You will never be able to select rows from t1 which have no corresponding joined rows in t2. And if you are happy with INNER JOIN, just use it explicitly. Same results means that rows joined. If you really need left join functionality in some cases, then second query works wrong. It works the same as INNER join. Just test with data absent in t2 and you will get no rows returned